# How to bind md-select(s) generated in an ng-repeat to different models?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<div layout="row" class="row" layout-xs="column" ng-repeat="dataset in datasetsEnv">
<div class="large-12 columns end" flex>
    <md-input-container layout="row" flex>
        <label>Environment setting for dataset {{dataset.datasetName}}:</label>
        <md-select ng-model="model.environments" style="min-width:410px;">
            <md-option ng-repeat="environment in dataset.environments" value="{{environment.DbEnvironmentId}}" ng-selected="isUserEnvSelected(environment)">{{environment.DisplayName}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
        <div></div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

With the above code I am generating a number mdSelect directives but my problem is that they all bind to one model `ng-model="model.environments"`. Is there a way to bind each generated mdSelect to a unique model which I can refer to later?

Comment: can you a provide a codepen with your controller and dataset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be ok.

```
<div layout="row" class="row" layout-xs="column" ng-repeat="dataset in datasetsEnv">
  <div class="large-12 columns end" flex>
     <md-input-container layout="row" flex>
        <label>Environment setting for dataset {{dataset.datasetName}}:</label>
      <md-select ng-model="dataset.selectedEnvironment" style="min-width:410px;">
        <md-option ng-repeat="environment in dataset.environments" value="{{environment.DbEnvironmentId}}" ng-selected="isUserEnvSelected(environment)">{{environment.DisplayName}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    <div></div>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this :

```
<div layout="row" class="row" layout-xs="column" ng-repeat="dataset in datasetsEnv">
  <div class="large-12 columns end" flex>
     <md-input-container layout="row" flex>
        <label>Environment setting for dataset {{dataset.datasetName}}:</label>
      <md-select ng-model="model.environments.dataset[datasetName]" style="min-width:410px;">
        <md-option ng-repeat="environment in dataset.environments" value="{{environment.DbEnvironmentId}}" ng-selected="isUserEnvSelected(environment)">{{environment.DisplayName}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    <div></div>
</md-input-container>
```

This will add a property `dataset` to `model.environments` with `dataset` being an `array` with `datasetname` equal to model value.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, I saw an example like that on another question but it doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: What's the reason behind it not working,have you tried anything at all??

Comment: The reason is that it doesn't add the property dataset to model.environments. The other thing I have tried is having an array array initialized in the controller and added a watch on the model to track changes  but that's not practical and produces wrong results.

Comment: can you a provide a codepen with your controller and dataset ?